# WLM, error 8e5e0211

Tags: windows-vista, windows-live-messenger

I know this isn't really a question worth putting on here, but does anybody know what could cause this error,  the microsoft gurus say it's just the contacts log is corrupt and to delete and and let it rebuild itself, but that doesn't seem to work all that well.

I read another chat about it saying it's because the hard drive is to full, not sure if that one's on the mark or not as the hard drive has had the same space on it for weeks and never had the issue.

Comment: by "doesn't work all that well", you mean that you've done that, but it still gives you that error?

Comment: Indeed that's what I mean.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer your question "what could cause this error", file corruption (what the root cause of the error is) could be caused by a number of things. If the application froze or was running when Windows crashed or the power was interrupted, it is possible that data was "half written" to the file and, when WLM reads it now it can't understand the file and calls it corrupt.

Comment: That's just the thing, the computer didn't crash which is why I asked, and on a side note, any ideas on fixing it.